# Setting COLORRANGE for rasters with variable minimum and maximum value in MapServer?

Tags: raster, openlayers, wms, layers, mapserver

I have a series of rasters picturing the same phenomenon/product eg. the accumulated precipitation and I use the same mapfile for all. Naturally the minimum is always zero but maximum is variable from dataset to dataset. But so far I know only how to set the COLORRANGE directive to fixed ranges of values like for example below:

```
CLASS
  EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 15 AND [pixel] < 20)
  STYLE
    COLORRANGE 74 120 182 50 87 160
    DATARANGE 15 20
    RANGEITEM "pixel"
  END
END
```

So, is it possible to replace the 15 and 20 from the above example with the raster dependant minimum and maximum pixels value?

I know that I could probably set it by obtaining the values prior to the setting of the WMS source and sending them together with the other source parameters to the CGI as min=0... and setting them n the mapfile via %min%, %max%. But I am interested if mapfile is able to extract this info on its own.